# How to crop a temp image with Paperclip and store it in Amazon S3 in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, crop, temporary-files, jcrop

I'm having a great trouble trying to do some out-of-ordinary tricks with paperclip.
This is my situation:
My app users have an avatar image and my idea is to let them crop their avatars through Jcrop. My app is hosted in Heroku so that I must to upload the images to Amazon S3.
I've used this popular [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?view=asciicast) to implement the cropping functionality but it requires to process two times the images. Here is where the problems started.

I think than a posible solution might be not process the images in the first time (when the user selectes an image) but do it the second. I've implemented this code in my controller:

```
    def change_avatar
      @user = current_user
      paperclip_parameters = params[:user][:avatar] #first time call

      if @temp_image_object.present? || params[:avatar].present?
        if check_crop_params  #second controller call
          @user.avatar = File.new(@user.tmp_avatar_path) #overrides the 
          redirect_to @user, notice: t("messages.update.user.avatar") if @user.save
        else    #first controller call
          @temp_path = @user.generate_temp_image(paperclip_parameters)
          @user.tmp_avatar_path = @new_path #store the custom path to retrieve it in the second call
          render :action => 'avatar_crop' if @user.save
        end
      end
    end

    def check_crop_params
      !params[:user][:crop_x].blank? && !params[:user][:crop_y].blank? && !params[:user][:crop_w].blank? && !params[:user][:crop_h ].blank?
    end
```

and in my user model:

```
  #this method copies the original image tempfile when user upload the image to a custom path and returns the custom path
  def generate_temp_image(paperclip_parameters)
    uploaded_img_path = uploaded_img.tempfile.path

    temp_dir = Rails.root.join('public/tmp')
    Dir.mkdir(temp_dir) unless Dir.exists?(temp_dir)

    FileUtils.cp(uploaded_img.tempfile, temp_dir)

    new_path = uploaded_img_path
  end
```

I also have the custom processor for jcrop, that takes the crop variables when proccessing the images. 
When I upload an image (first controller call) the change_avatar method works well but when I crop the image (second controller call) the image isn't cropped, paperclip creates the image styles files but ignores the cropping I did.

Any ideas? what I should do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten an small detail.. looking in the server logs I realized that the paperclip process wasn't cropping the images, so I looked in my custom processor and I find that it depended on the crop parameters : crop_x, crop_y, crop_w, crop_h.
For some reason this parameters didn't reach the processor, so the images never were going to be cropped. All I had to do is to manually assign this params to the user vars, and it works!

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy is direct-upload original upload to s3. [This tutorial](http://odysseyonrails.com/articles/11) has an example talking about how to run the paperclip post-processing method after uploading to S3. It also discussed how to avoid the Heroku H12 error in case the post-processing takes too long on S3.

You may also check out [this article](http://odysseyonrails.com/articles/10). It has a demo code using paperclip and jcrop.